# Jquery open all parent ul with list link

Tags: jquery

I have a menu structure like:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">HR</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Address</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="listcountrymaster.aspx">Country</a></li>
                    <li><a href="listregionmaster.aspx">Region</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Assets</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ListVendorMaster.aspx">Vendor</a></li>
                     <li><a href="Listassetmaster.aspx">Asset</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

what I want to do is:
I want to open all parent `<ul>` above the link with `href="ListVendorMaster.aspx"`

something I have tried is:

```
var openmenu = 'ListVendorMaster.aspx';
$('#menu ul').hide();
if(openmenu)
{
    $('a[href="'+openmenu+'"]').closest('ul').show();
}
```

with this I am able to open only one level parent ul.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `closest()` use `parents()`.

jQuery [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: It would be wise to note that "closest" finds the first match where "parents" finds all matches. In your case, you want parents. I might also switch $('#menu ul').hide();

Answer (score 0):

```
if(openmenu)
{
    $('a[href="'+openmenu+'"]').parent().parent('ul').show();
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SqBYs/)**